# How to sort html elements according to array values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to sort html elements with jQuery based off the order of items in a data attribute on an input. "data-order"

See the code setup here, but I am stuck.

http://jsbin.com/cixolonoqe/1/edit?html,js,output

HTML:

```
<div id="control">
   <input type="hidden" data-order="title,text,date">
  </div>
  <div id="parts">

    <p class="date part">20 January 2014</p>
    <h5 class="title part">Some Title</h5>
    <p class="text part">A line of Text</p>

  </div>
```

jQuery:

```
var input =  $('#control input');
var partsOrder = input.attr("data-order");

var parts = $('#parts');

parts.find('.part').each(function(i) {
      $(this).attr('data-index', 'index' + i);
});

//Make array from data-order attribute
var partsArray = partsOrder.split(',');

 $.partsArray(json, function(i, val) {


  //modify html order



 });
```

If data-order string changes, I want the html to re order accordingly.

title,text,date vs date,text,title

So far I have added a new data attribute with the original index onto the parts. And created an array from the data-order string so it can be looped through and modify the html.

But I am unable to get my head around it.

Comment: Could you click edit and post the code here, instead of the link.  Questions ideally include it to survive link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the target index on the elements, get them in an array, sort the array on the index, and then rearrange the elements according to the array:

```
var partsOrder = $('#control input').attr("data-order").split(',');

var parts = $('#parts');

// set target index for elements
$.each(partsOrder, function(i, v){
  $('.' + v, parts).data('index', i);
});

// sort array on index
var items = parts.find('.part');
items.sort(function(a,b){ return $(a).data('index') - $(b).data('index'); });

// move elements into array order
parts.append(items);
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/fejegeyoco/2/edit

Comment: How would I go about a hiding an html part if it is not listed in the data-order attr?

Comment: @Andy: You could hide them all, then in the loop where you set the target index add `.show()` to show the ones that are in the list.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes that you are looping through and creating perhaps multiple sets of three within your div and does not require you to edit your HTML.

```
var input =  $('#control input');
var partsOrder = input.attr("data-order");
var parts = $('#parts');
var partsArray = partsOrder.split(',');

var $part = parts.find('.part');

var groupNum = 0;
$part.each(function(k,v) {
  if (k === 0 || k % 3 === 0) {
    var $div = $(v).wrap('<div class="group" data-group="' + groupNum + '"></div>');
    $(v).attr('data-group', groupNum);
    var $second = $($part.get(k+1)).attr('data-group', groupNum);
    var $third = $($part.get(k+2)).attr('data-group', groupNum);
    $second.remove();
    $third.remove();
    $div.append($second);
    $div.append($third);
    groupNum++;
  }  
});

for (var i = 0; i < groupNum; i++) {
  var $group = $('.group[data-group="' + i + '"]');
  for (var j = 0; j < partsArray.length; j++) {
    var $thePart = $group.find('.' + partsArray[j]);  
    $thePart.remove();
    $group.append($thePart);
  }
}

$('.group').unwrap();
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/natahunapi/4/edit)

Comment: You can't wrap an element by using `before` and `after` to add starting and ending tags. The DOM consists of elements, not tags, so you can only add complete elements to it.